# DataGrid not displaying all results when reading from DB, C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have the following code which reads from a database and is supposed to display in a datagrid. The query works fine and returns the results expected. Indeed I have fed the data into a combobox without problem. The problem is when I add them to a Datagrid, one result is displayed and the subsequently added lines to the datagrid don't contain any data.

```
        string SQLstring = "select * from table";
        SqlCommand MDTRoleSting = new SqlCommand(SQLstring,MDTConn());
        MDTSQLReader = MDTRoleSting.ExecuteReader();

        int i = 0;
        while (MDTSQLReader.Read())
        {

            dgvPackagesAndDPs.Rows[i].Cells["Packages"].Value = MDTSQLReader["Packages"].ToString();
            i+=1;
            dgvPackagesAndDPs.Rows.Add();

        }
        MDTSQLReader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it assumes the grid has a blank row in it when the loop begins.  If it doesn't, move your Rows.Add() to the first line inside the loop.

Comment: OMG. Really thought I'd already tried that. Feel a little bit silly. Thank you!